# SAS - create a new variable which contains the sum of another variable per quarter

Tags: sas

I have a dataset that looks like:

```
qy             balance
2010 Q1   10
2010 Q1   10
2010 Q1   10
2010 Q2   20
2010 Q2   20
2010 Q3   20
2010 Q4   50
2011 Q1   100
2011 Q2   200
2011 Q3   300
```

and I would like to create a new variable which contains the sum per quarter. Desired output:

```
qy             balance    sum_balance
2010 Q1   10             30
2010 Q1   10             30
2010 Q1   10             30
2010 Q2   20             60
2010 Q2   20             60
2010 Q3   20             60
2010 Q4   50             50
2011 Q1   100           100
2011 Q2   200           200
2011 Q3   300           300
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `proc sql` and `sum` function:

```
proc sql;
   create table want as
   select qy,
          balance,
          sum(balance) as sum_balance
   from have
   group by qy;
quit;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative data step approach

```
data have;
input qy $ 1-7 balance;
datalines;
2010 Q1 10
2010 Q1 10
2010 Q1 10
2010 Q2 20
2010 Q2 20
2010 Q3 20
2010 Q4 50
2011 Q1 100
2011 Q2 200
2011 Q3 300
;

data want;
    do until (last.qy);
        set have;
        by qy;
        sum_balance + balance;
    end;
    do until (last.qy);
        set have;
        by qy;
        output;
    end;
    sum_balance=0;
run;
```